# How to get the last index of quill editor?

Tags: quill

I want to use the [insertEmbed](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#insertembed) method of the quill editor to insert stuff at the end of the content inside the quill editor. So what I need to do, is find the last index of the quill editor so I can do `lastIndex + 1` for the first parameter:

`insertEmbed(index: Number, type: String, value: any, source: String = 'api')`

Which should insert what I want at the very end of the content.

I've searched the docs and the only thing I see similar to what I want is [getLines](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getline-experimental).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this as the index:

```
quill.scroll.length()
```

Answer (score 4):

Quill has a [`getLength`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getlength) method:

```
quill.getLength()
```